# Losing state data on page refresh 'Cannot read properties of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am fetching all teams from an API in my App.js file and storing all the fetched teams in an array, the state is managed by Redux.

Here is my App.js where i use the getTeams() function to send the teams to Redux.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { teamActions } from './store/team-slice';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Teams from './components/pages/Teams';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import TeamInfo from './components/pages/TeamInfo';

const App = ()=> {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const getTeams = () => {
    fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/teams`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch(teamActions.sortTeams(data.data)));
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
    getTeams();
    }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}></Route>
        <Route exact path={'/teams'} component={Teams}></Route>
        <Route exact path={'/team/:teamName'} component={TeamInfo}></Route>
      </Switch>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In Redux I store the teams in an array called totalTeams:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const teamInitialState = {totalTeams: [], easternTeams:[], westernTeams:[]};

const teamSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'team',
    initialState: teamInitialState,
    reducers: {
        sortTeams(state, action){
            state.totalTeams = action.payload;
            state.westernTeams = action.payload.filter(team => team.conference === 'West');
            state.easternTeams = action.payload.filter(team => team.conference === 'East');
        }
    }
});

export const teamActions = teamSlice.actions;
export default teamSlice;
```

I then have a "Team Info" page where I take the team name from the url using useParams
to filter out the current team from the redux array of totalTeams.

I then use that data to fill the page with the team info, everything works until I refresh the page, I then lose all data.

Shouldn't all the data still be there since I am using the Redux array to find the team info? The fetch to the API is made on every page reload and the data is saved to the array so why am I losing state?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from '../layout/Container';
import classes from './TeamInfo.module.css'

const TeamInfo = () => {
  const teams = useSelector(state => state.team.totalTeams);
  const params = useParams();
  const teamSlug = params.teamName;
  const teamNoDashes = teamSlug.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  const currentTeam = teams && teams.find(team => team.full_name.toLowerCase() === teamNoDashes);

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={classes['team-info-container']}>
        <div><img src={`/img/team-logos-grid/${teamSlug}.png`} alt={teamSlug} /></div>
        <div>
          <h2>{currentTeam.full_name}</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>City: {currentTeam.city}</li>
            <li>Division: {currentTeam.division}</li>
            <li>Conference: {currentTeam.conference}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default TeamInfo;
```

Comment: Please include the full error trace.

Comment: @ivanatias Even if I'm fetching the full team list on every page reload? Shouldn't I be able to just use the .find() method on the totalTeams array in Redux since it always has the teams?

Comment: Try using [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). I think the problem is due to the data being `undefined` on first render. It gets populated after the fetching is completed. I do agree that you should include the full error trace tho.

Comment: @ivanatias You were right, the problem was it was trying to parse out the data from an empty array, I added validation to make sure the data is fetched and stored in the array first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you need check exist of `data`, and then fields in this object:

```
loading || (data && (!data.me || !data.getPlaces)) ? ...
```